# Button not getting the focus

Tags: wpf, vb.net, focus

I have a textbox, a DataGrid and a button.

When textbox gets focus DataGrid is Visible.
User writes some text in textbox and the matching text in DataGrid's first Column is selected.

While user presses the enter key the Value of the selected Row's First Column is transferred to the textbox and then DataGrid hides and button below the textbox gets focus. Here is the code :

```
If e.Key = Key.Return Then
    Dim ue As FrameworkElement = e.OriginalSource
    txt.Text = DataGrid1.SelectedItem(0).ToString
    ue.MoveFocus(New TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next))
End If
```

This Code works fine. I want the same behavior while user presses `Ctrl + Down_Arrow`.

Here is the code for doing that but it did not work. I mean it selects the Selected Row's First Column's Value and transfers it to the TextBox. But it does not transfer the focus to the button. I mean textbox does not loose focus.

```
If (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) = True Or Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl) = True) And e.Key = Key.Down Then
    Dim ue As FrameworkElement = e.OriginalSource
    txt.Text = DataGrid1.SelectedItem(0).ToString
    ue.MoveFocus(New TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Down))
End If
```

I have tried the word `Next` instead of `Down` in the above code but it alos doesn't work.

Comment: I prefer the `OrElse` and `AndAlso` booleans operators for these things.

Comment: Tried it just now but Don't feel any change.

Comment: Is that code getting hit? The TextBox normally handles the arrow keys. If it is being hit does the movefocus call succeed? In which case something would have to be shifting focus back.

Comment: yes, The code is being hit but focus does not change.

Comment: Now I inserted a new button in the designer. While Pressing enter I get focus to the old button, while pressing ctrl + Down_Arrow I get focus to new button. This is the strange behavior.

Comment: Now I replaced all the buttons with textbox and now it works. I am confused with this strange behavior of wpf.